# Copy entire word document including tables to another using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

I need to copy the entire contents of a template to a new document. The problem is that tables just cannot be copied. Currently, my code takes care of copying styles like bold and italic.

```
def get_para_data(output_doc_name, paragraph):
    output_para = output_doc_name.add_paragraph()
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        output_run = output_para.add_run(run.text)
        # Run's bold data
        output_run.bold = run.bold
        # Run's italic data
        output_run.italic = run.italic
        # Run's underline data
        output_run.underline = run.underline
        # Run's color data
        output_run.font.color.rgb = run.font.color.rgb
        # Run's font data
        output_run.style.name = run.style.name
    # Paragraph's alignment data
    output_para.paragraph_format.alignment = 
paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment
input_doc=Document('templatemain.docx')
output_doc=Document()
for para in input_doc.paragraphs:
    get_para_data(output_doc, para)
output_doc.save('OutputDoc.docx')
```

Most of the help I've found for copying tables is to append them. But I am copying a template into a blank document so that doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Please clarify what kind of tables you have. You used the 'excel' tag on the post, do you have an embedded Excel spreadsheet? Or are these just regular formatted Word tables?

Comment: And what library are you using to open the word document? I'm presuming it's python-docx?

Comment: I am using python-docx. Excel I've used in the rest of my code. Included it here by mistake. It has no relevance in this snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only iterating over the `.paragraphs` attribute of the document. Tables are listed separately, via the `.tables` attribute.

You'd need to loop over all the child elements of the document body together, in document order, or otherwise you end up with all the paragraphs and tables bunched together. The `python-docx` library doesn't offer this functionality directly, you'd need to [create your own iterator](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40).

For example, a simplified version would be:

```
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.oxml.table import CT_Tbl
from docx.table import Table
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph


# select only paragraphs or table nodes
for child in input_doc.element.body.xpath('w:p | w:tbl'):
    if isinstance(child, CT_P):
        paragraph = Paragraph(child, input_doc)
        get_para_data(output_doc, paragraph)
    elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
        table = Table(child, input_doc)
        # do something with the table
```

Tables can only be contained in the document body, in table cells (so nested inside other tables), in headers and footers, footnotes, and tracked changes, but *not* inside paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. Could you explain what child and iterchildren are? This code isn't really working for me. There are no errors but no change in the output either. Even the text in paragraph isn't getting copied now.

Comment: @nonamelowlife: docx is a XML format, and the python-docx library essentially wraps XML elements via the lxml library, which supplies methods like `iterchildren` (see http://lxml.de/1.3/api.html#iteration). `child` is then a special python docx XML element, a subclass of the `lxml` `etree.Element` class. Classes like `CT_P` and `CT_Tbl` are essentially implementation details of how the Python docx project works, but unfortunately the project hasn't given us a better way to find both paragraphs *and* tables.

Comment: @nonamelowlife: I've tested this on several documents, and the code works just fine. Are you *certain* that `input_doc.tables` is not an empty list?

Comment: @nonamelowlife: on the other hand, I may have misunderstood where those tables are located. If not part of the body of the document, where *do* they reside?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've decided to drop python-docx for copying. Shutil seems much easier. I'm sort of on a time crunch.

Comment: And I've seen the github link you shared. This seems to be working for everyone, so you're probably right.

Comment: @nonamelowlife: I also double-checked the [ECMA standard documentation](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) on where tables can be defined; the above loop is guaranteed to find all paragraphs and tables in a word document.

Comment: @nonamelowlife: however, if you only need to make a full copy of the document, then yes, `shutil.copyfile()` is going to be so much easier.